# Using Sweet Alert as a window.confirm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sweetalert

I am having trouble finding a way to use sweet alert as a promise to resolve a possilble case here is what i'm trying to to do

```
function void continueOn(){

    return swal({
        title: "Continue?",
        text: "Do you want to continue?",
        icon: "warning",
        buttons: ["no","yes"],
    }).then((result) => { return result})
}

return (
    <Button 
        onclick={() => {
            if(!doContinue || continueOn()){
                console.log("Here")
            }
        }}

)
```

What is happening is when it hits continueOn() it just truly does continue on before the user can even answers if they want to continue or not. I do want to check if they are in doContinue Mode before I ask them directly. So order does matter.

Comment: Hello, if your issue was resolved by the below answer, consider marking as accepted by clicking the grey tick next to it :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out this example code:

```js
const doContinue = false;

const continueOn = () => {
    return swal({
        title: "Continue?",
        text: "Do you want to continue?",
        icon: "warning",
        buttons: ["no","yes"],
    })
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={() => {
          if(!doContinue){
            continueOn()
            .then(result => {
              // Here do what you want  
              console.log(result)
            })                
          } else{
            console.log("Popup not shown")
          }
      }}
      >Continue</button> 
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is that really going to be equilavlant to an or statement though?

Comment: Could explain a little what your OR statement is doing, maybe I can adapt the code for that

Comment: You want to show the confirm box if `doContinue` is `false`, am I right?

Comment: Well if they are in continue one mode, I want to console.log, but they could also over ride it by answering that prompt. I believe yours is how to do an && statement

Comment: Yeah that is what I was trying to do.

Comment: @SetupG That's what is happening, I added an else condition too if the `doContinue` is `true`